# Syntax for retrieving variable using another variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I'm trying to find the UUID of a VM based on it's hostname.  I'm not sure what is missing in my syntax here, but I've tried several different methods.  Here is the sample playbook I'm working with currently:

```yaml
---

- name: Test taking snapshot by UUID
  hosts: tst000.company.com
  vars_files:
    - vars/credentials.yml

  tasks:
    - name: Gather all registered virtual machines
      vmware_vm_facts:
        hostname: 'vcenter.company.com'
        username: '{{ vcenter.username }}'
        password: '{{ vcenter.password }}'
        validate_certs: False
      delegate_to: localhost
      register: vmfacts

    - debug:
        var: vmfacts.virtual_machines.{{ ansible_facts['hostname'] }}.uuid

    - set_fact:
        vm_uuid: "{{ lookup('vars', 'vmfacts.virtual_machines.' + ansible_facts['hostname'] + '.uuid') }}"
```

Results are as follows:

```
 Identity added: /opt/tmp/awx_2507_ithHYD/credential_3
 (/opt/tmp/awx_2507_ithHYD/credential_3) Vault password: 

 PLAY [Test taking snapshot by UUID]
 ********************************************


 TASK [Gathering Facts]
 ********************************************************* ok: [tst000.company.com]

 TASK [Gather all registered virtual machines]
 ********************************** ok: [tst000.company.com -> localhost]

 TASK [debug]
 ******************************************************************* ok: [tst000.company.com] => {
     "vmfacts.virtual_machines.tst000.uuid": "421d2491-8896-e52f-e4f5-5118687ce0e9" }

 TASK [set_fact]
 **************************************************************** fatal: [tst000.company.com]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task
 includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: No
 variable found with this name:
 vmfacts.virtual_machines.tst000.uuid\\n\\nThe error appears to
 have been in '/var/lib/awx/projects/quick-stuff/test_snapshot.yml':
 line 21, column 7, but may\\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the
 exact syntax problem.\\n\\nThe offending line appears to be:\\n\\n\\n 
 - set_fact:\\n      ^ here\\n"}

 PLAY RECAP
 ********************************************************************* tst000.company.com : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0   
 failed=1
```

In the debug and set_fact modules, you can see that the ansible_facts['hostname]' properly places the hostname as needed, however, it returns the proper value in the debug module, but is claiming there is no variable found by that name in the set_fact module.  I'm not sure what is wrong with my syntax here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to use the `lookup` in that way, since `vars` and its `hostvars` friend are effectively `dict`s:

```
- set_fact:
    vm_uuid: "{{ vmfacts.virtual_machines[ansible_facts['hostname']].uuid }}"
```

Comment: I've tried that formatting as well.  Doesn't seem to like that either.

Comment: Can you post the error from that version, as there must be something I'm overlooking

Comment: `TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
fatal: [tst000.company.com]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected name or number. String: {{ vmfacts.virtual_machines.['ansible_facts['hostname']'].uuid }}"}`

Comment: the extra single quotes were a follow-up attempt at eliciting a different result.  The error was the same without them

Comment: For anyone that stumbles upon this, the answer was to drop the leading ',' before the nested variable in the syntax as Matthew suggested but i missed.  He get's the credit, but this is important!